# CodeIgniter upload video from localhost to YouTube

Tags: php, codeigniter, youtube, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to upload videos from my local server to my YouTube account. I have been trying to implement this sample from https://github.com/jimdoescode/CodeIgniter-YouTube-API-Library but it obviously is deprecated and returns "consumer key is not registered".

I have successfully done a authentication but any new libraries that supports the newer YouTube v3 API would be greatly appreciated. I'm using CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the official PHP API created by youtube:

1. [Official PHP API provided by YouTube (link towards github)](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)
2. [Google APIs Client Library for PHP](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/)
3. [Google APIs Client Library for PHP Get Started](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/get_started)

Not sure how you missed it since one of the links was put in the deprecated section of the link you provided.

[Here is an example of a fileupload that can be found on the github](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/fileupload.php)

**All information past this point was taken straight from the github:**

**Description:**

> The Google API Client Library enables you to work with Google APIs
>   such as Google+, Drive, or YouTube on your server.

**Basic Example from the github:**

> See the examples/ directory for examples of the key client features.

```
<?php

  require_once 'google-api-php-client/autoload.php'; // or wherever autoload.php is located

  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
  $client->setDeveloperKey("YOUR_APP_KEY");

  $service = new Google_Service_Books($client);
  $optParams = array('filter' => 'free-ebooks');
  $results = $service->volumes->listVolumes('Henry David Thoreau', $optParams);

  foreach ($results as $item) {
    echo $item['volumeInfo']['title'], "<br /> \n";
  }
```

**Message from the google library page:**

> This client library is in beta. We will make an effort to support the
>   library and maintain backwards compatibility in the future, but we
>   reserve the right to make incompatible changes when necessary.

Comment: apparently i'm absorbing this eyeopener i'll try implementing and update with what i have.